# POSTing a file to resteasy

Tags: java, file-upload, jboss, resteasy, wildfly

I'm getting the error at the bottom of this post. Can anyone spot the issue?

Resteasy HTTP call:

```
@POST
@Path("/")
public void upload(final @MultipartForm FileUploadForm form) {
    LOG.info(String.format("/%s/%s/%s/%s", form.getA(), form.getB(), form.getC(), form.getD()));
}
```

Associated Java model:

```
private class FileUploadForm {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    private String d;

    private byte[] file;

    @FormParam("a") @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public void setA(final String a) { this.a = a; }
    public String getA() { return a; }

    @FormParam("b") @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public void setB(final String b) { this.b = b; }
    public String getB() { return b; }

    @FormParam("c") @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public void setC(final String c) { this.c = c; }
    public String getC() { return c; }

    @FormParam("d") @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public void setD(final String d) { this.d = d; }
    public String getD() { return d; }

    @FormParam("file") @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public void setFile(final byte[] file) { this.file = file; }
    public byte[] getFile() { return file; }
}
```

JQuery calling code:

```
$('div#upload form').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        'url': '/api/',
        'type': 'POST',
        'data': new FormData($('div#upload form')[0]),
        'contentType': false,
        'cache': false,
        'processData': false
    });

    return false;
});
```

Also get the same result calling from curl:

```
    curl -F file=testimage.jpg http://hostname/api/
```

Error:

```
18:11:33,890 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler] (default task-37) Failed executing POST /: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormAnnotationReader.readFrom(MultipartFormAnnotationReader.java:64) [resteasy-multipart-provider-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:59) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(ServerReaderInterceptorContext.java:62) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:51) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalVerificationInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(DigitalVerificationInterceptor.java:32) [resteasy-crypto-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:53) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:59) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:53) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:150) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:88) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:111) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:272) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:229) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:216) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invokePropagateNotFound(SynchronousDispatcher.java:217) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:224) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:59) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.1.Final.jar:]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta3.jar:1.0.0.Beta3]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta3.jar:1.0.0.Beta3]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta3.jar:1.0.0.Beta3]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta3.jar:1.0.0.Beta3]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta3.jar:1.0.0.Beta3]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:115) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta3.jar:1.0.0.Beta3]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationCallHandler.java:52) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Beta3.jar:1.0.0.Beta3]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Beta3.jar:1.0.0.Beta3]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:65) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta3.jar:1.0.0.Beta3]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:70) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Beta3.jar:1.0.0.Beta3]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Beta3.jar:1.0.0.Beta3]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextCreationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextCreationHandler.java:54)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Beta3.jar:1.0.0.Beta3]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:185) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta3.jar:1.0.0.Beta3]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta3.jar:1.0.0.Beta3]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta3.jar:1.0.0.Beta3]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:107) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta3.jar:1.0.0.Beta3]
        at io.undertow.server.HttpHandlers.executeRootHandler(HttpHandlers.java:36) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Beta3.jar:1.0.0.Beta3]
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:629) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Beta3.jar:1.0.0.Beta3]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ugh. I seem to have figured it out. FileUploadForm was an inner class within the Resteasy class with the upload method.

Splitting it out into its own class has got it working. Crazy.